# How to Upload json file in mvc4 to enter data in tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have json file generated from my database in the following format

```
[{"UserInfoID":"57adb1e8-27ab-e311-afb2-eca86bf5549a","DbType":"OFFLINE","UserID":"d3f3b6a6-77aa-436a-a73c-d6655566888b","GraphID":"56adb1e8-27ab-e311-afb2-eca86bf5549a","UserLevelEnumId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Title":"Mr/Mrs","FirstName":"Neeraj","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Mehta","Birthdate":"\/Date(699388200000)\/","Gender":"Male","Email":"neer.srmiet@gmail.com","MobileNo":"+918950333123","Country":"India","Zipcode":133201,"UserLevel":999,"CountFollowers":0,"CountFollows":0,"CountFiles":0,"CountPhotos":0,"Quote":"Empowering Education","AvatarURL":"/UserFiles/Images/X50/IMAG1289_1vv4djTgspjjsl87fquality_50.jpg","PosterURL":null,"isVerified":true,"VerificationCount":0,"UserEnumType":"USER","UserCreatorId":"d3f3b6a6-77aa-436a-a73c-d6655566888b"}
```

and i have downloaded this data in a file and now i want to upload this data in other database having same structure and same attribute 
How can i upload this from a file and suggestion?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking. you are asking how to upload .json file from a client? or how to create a new table that matches this json object? (if so what database you are using)

Comment: @Aviran i am using mvc4 database and i have two database one in client and one server .i want client database to be downloaded in json file and upload it to serverdatabase

Comment: Are you using Entity framework database?

Comment: @Aviran yes i am using Entity Framework Database

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that match this object if you don't have it yet (lets call this class 'user').
2. If you want to upload this json data using ajax create the following action:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult(User user) {
   // Add input validation here.
   // Add the user entity to the database.
   UsersContext context = new UsersContext();
   context.Users.Add(user);
   context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
   ```

Comment: i am passing this json data from view so not able to post data in User class

Comment: Do you pass the json data using Post method to the right action, and the action is hit with an empty User object?

Comment: function UploadCart() {
            
            $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "Post",
                     url: "/Offline/UploadCart",
                     dataType: "html",
                     data: { UserInfo: userdata },
                     success: function (data) {
                         },

Comment: i have taken User class as Userinfo